# How to specify object instantiation order in guice?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, guice

I'm creating two objects in two Guice modules, `Object1` and `Object2`. Both these objects use `Object3`. How can I control the order in which Guice instantiates `Object1` and `Object2` (`Object 1` before `2`) as the state of `Object3` set by `Object1` is required for `Object2` ? In spring this is similar to having a `@DependsOn`. But I couldn't find anything similar in Guice.

```
GuiceModule1
    Object1(Object3)
GuiceModule2
    Object2(Object3)
```

A way that I think could solve this is by passing `Object2` as a parameter when constructing `Object1`, but that doesn't sound the right way as I have to do this just to define dependency creation order.

Comment: Guice by default should arranges the initialization order correctly. In spring the usage of @dependsOn is done to workaround problems like an object with static dependency not handled by spring. A more specific example will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't enforce injection order in Guice via some annotation or built-in mechanism.

But you can trick Guice to enforce injection order by means of requiring class `Object2` to hold a reference to `Object1` without doing anything with the reference. It's definitely not clean but gets the job done easily.

**Hint for dependency injection best practices**

If it's possible you should restructure your class design in a way that injection order doesn't matter. The dependency order should be the only driver of injection order and this is where Guice or other DI frameworks excel.

Perhaps that's the reason why Guice doesn't provide such a built-in mechanism to enforce injection order as it comes with some other cost such as maintenance of the annotation and even some contradiction if your references change drastically so that the annotation would be the opposite of what your depdency graph says. I think you see where I'm heading to.

Without more information about your app it's difficult to give advice about how to do it "better".

Anyway I hope it helped!